# Laravel New API Not Working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel (5.3.28) and I'm running into an issue with my very first api route not working. I've followed the Laravel docs and can create a new project and can navigate to the Laravel splash screen indicating it's working. I added the following route to `routes/api.php` to test if I can consume the end-point, but I get an error:

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

**error**

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I have a dedicated CentOS box running XAMPP for my web server. the address to hit the end-point is `http://10.0.0.200/test/api/public/foo`.

I'm read that my `.htaccess` file should be edited, but the few examples I found match what I already have, so I'm a little lost on what to do.

Here is the output for `php artisan route:list`:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/foo  |      | Closure | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: You need to configure your web server to make `path/to/laravel/public` as your root directory.

Comment: I do that in the `httpd.conf` file right?

Comment: Try http:// 10.0.0.200/api/foo

Comment: @Rishi - I tried that and get `Object not found!`

Comment: @Mike, you should create a Virtual Host on apache. Take a look here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Using Virtual Host will allow you to host many projects on same apache.
If you don't want this, just look for `DocumentRoot` on your httpd.conf

Comment: Test endpoint should be `http://10.0.0.200/test/api/foo` Here are some repos that work for exactly what you are trying to do: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-passport   https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-consumer

Comment: Also, I would not suggest using XAMPP, Try using a Laravel Homestead instance... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead

Comment: http://10.0.0.200/test/api/public/ is the root URL I assume. If yes, then you need to hit http://10.0.0.200/test/api/public/api/foo

Comment: @naneri - that worked. Now how do I get the url to be `10.0.0.200/test/api/foo` It's not a huge deal, but having `public/api` seems ugly to me?

Comment: @Mike you see - I think that your project lies in the folder test/api, what you need is to reconfigure apache\nginx to route all requests going to
10.0.0.200/test/ , to start going to  {webser root}/test/api/public . This is done in web server configuration files.

Comment: @naneri - okay I'll get that part figured out. Go ahead and create and answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mike added the answer

Comment: Routes you access via the web (a browser) should be inserted into `routes/web.php` – what if you add your routes there?

Comment: Laravel recommend using the ``artisan`` machinery to do your development tasks. This include running a built-in web server with ``php artisan serve`` in a terminal in your root directory. http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/282/running-phps-built-in-web-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.0.0.200/test/api/public is the root URL I assume. If yes, then you need to hit 10.0.0.200/test/api/public/api/foo

I think that your project lies in the folder test/api, what you need is to reconfigure apache\nginx to route all requests going to 10.0.0.200/test/ , to start going to {webser root}/test/api/public . This is done in web server configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the `artisan` commands to do several development tasks, such as running a built-in web server. You can do this by opening a new terminal inside the root directory of your project (where the `artisan` script is located) and run the following command :

```
php artisan serve
```

This should notice you with the URL of the built-in web server. You can then access it through your web browser. Generally,  `http://localhost:8000`

This way, you'll be able to access your route which heads to `http://localhost:8000/foo` and in which you should find the page that says `Hello world` as your return in your closure.

Comment: I use a separate box which has all my Laravel files. I'm not sure the best way to develop laravel and get production files. So I'm just using my web server to develop on.